# Floquet Theory : zero equilibirum stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

Wondering if someone could explain exactly what it means when someone says "zero equilibirium is unstable because the floquet multiplier is greater than 1". I understand the FM part but I don't know what zero equilibirum means. Can I just say the floquet system is unstable ??
Thanks

Comment: Consider adding the excerpt from the article or book that you are reading to the body of your question. It will be much easier to understand what did they want to say exactly.